# Github Action increase timeout

Tags: github-actions

I have a github action workflow to run jmeter tests.
this is a snippet -

```
name: JMeter Automation
on:
 workflow_dispatch:

defaults:
 run:
  shell: bash

jobs:
 JMETER_TEST:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Check out repository code
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      ref: main

  - name: Set up Java
    uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: '11'

  - name: Download JMeter
    run: |
      wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.3.tgz
      tar -xvf apache-jmeter-5.4.3.tgz
      export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin

  - name: Download JMeter Plugins
    run: |
      mkdir -p $PWD/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/lib/ext
      wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-casutg-2.10.zip
      unzip -o jpgc-casutg-2.10.zip -d $PWD/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/
      
      wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-graphs-basic-2.0.zip
      unzip -o jpgc-graphs-basic-2.0.zip -d $PWD/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/
      
      wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-graphs-additional-2.0.zip
      unzip -o jpgc-graphs-additional-2.0.zip -d $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/

  - name: Set up JMeter properties
    run: |
      echo "HEAP=-Xms10g -Xmx20g" >> $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/jmeter.properties
      echo "jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true" >> $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/jmeter.properties

  - name: Run JMeter Tests
    working-directory: psr-scripts
    run: |
        mkdir ./results
        
        # Find all JMX files recursively within the subdirectories
        jmx_files_maxLoad=$(find . -name "*maxLoad.jmx" -type f)
                  
        # Iterate over the maxLoad JMX files
        for jmx_file_maxLoad in $jmx_files_maxLoad; do
          folder=$(dirname "$jmx_file_maxLoad")
          folder_base=$(basename "$folder")
          echo "$folder_base"
        
          # Execute JMeter test for each maxLoad JMX file
          jmx_file_maxLoad=$(basename "$jmx_file_maxLoad")
          echo "$jmx_file_maxLoad"
          cd "$folder"
          $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/jmeter -n -t "$jmx_file_maxLoad" -l "../results/${folder_base}_maxLoad.jtl"
          $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/bin/jmeter -n -t "$jmx_file_maxLoad" -l "../results/${folder_base}_maxLoad.csv"
          cd ..
        done

  - name: Upload Reports
    if: always()
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: JMeter Reports - ${{ github.run_number }}
      path: psr-scripts/results/
```

All this part of single workflow. under psr-scripts folder i have multiple subdirectories with jmx file.

On execution, workflow fails after 6 hours of execution. I think that is the maximum time a job can execute in github action. Manually these tests would take 7-8 hours to execute.

How can I increase the timeout so that workflow do no fails after 6 hours.

My thought -- to add multiple jobs for each subfolders in psr-scripts. but how would I dynamically create the jobs based on the subfolder identified?

Comment: One possible approach for multiple jobs: You can create a reusable workflow to run tests which will accept the directory that you want to run on. From the caller workflow, you can prepare a strategy matrix for these paths and pass it on to your reusable workflow which will run these in parallel.

Comment: Did you try configuring the default timeout though? Using [`jobs.<job_id>.timeout-minutes`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idtimeout-minutes)?